# CasperJS: When having two successive calls to fetchText, second one doesn't work

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

CasperJS version 1.1.0-beta3

```
casper.start(someLink);

function getUrl(link) {
    casper.thenOpen(basePath + link);
    casper.then(function() {

        var par1 = this.fetchText('body > table > tbody > tr > td > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > strong > span')   
        this.echo(par1);
        var par2 = this.fetchText('body > table > tbody > tr > td > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(3) > strong > span')   
        this.echo(par2);

    });
}

getUrl(someRelativeUrl);

casper.run(function() {
  this.echo('DONE!');
});
```

**Problem**: par1 displays the right value, par2 is empty.
I change their order, placing par2 before par1: in this case, par2 displays right and par1 is empty.

What am I doing wrong? Obviously, the fetchText lines are correct, and the CSS are correct, yet only the first one fetches: the next ones all remain empty.

**Edit**: Here's the actual html that gives the problems (stackoverflow somehow hides the  section and the DOCTYPE from the code). As simple as it gets:
    
    
    
    
    Details

```
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">
      <table width="1000" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td><table width="1000" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td width="217" valign="top" bgcolor="#E3E5E4"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              </table></td>
              <td width="783" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td align="right" bgcolor="#D4D6D5"><img src="top.jpg" width="180" height="179" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td width="97%">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>

                 <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                 </tr>

                 <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                          <td width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
                          <td width="49%"align="left" class="style10">POLE1: <strong><span class="style7">ADR1 </span></strong></td>
                          <td width="49%"align="left" class="style10">POLE2: <strong><span class="style7">ADR2 </span></strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>


                      </table></td>
                 </tr>

                              <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#170E13">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does it change if you add `;` behind the `fetchText` calls?

Comment: Nope, not working. Could it be some latency due to heavy calculations cause by the long css selector? I'm totally lost, after hours, I run into such issues, and programming stops being logical:(

Comment: No, that can't be it, because `fetchText` is entirely synchronous.

Comment: possible duplicate of [waitForSelector passes, but assertExists fails for the same selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835506/waitforselector-passes-but-assertexists-fails-for-the-same-selector)