# waitForSelector passes, but assertExists fails for the same selector

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, phantomjs, casperjs

When I call the following function, `waitForSelector` passes for 'selector', but `assertExists` fails for the same selector. How is it possible?

```
casper.waitForSelector(selector, function() {
    casper.test.assertExists(selector, sectionName + " opened up successfully.");
}, function() {
    casper.test.fail(sectionName + " did not load in given time");
}, max_timeout);
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/e8ac639985af50471441) is a complete example to reproduce the issue with an `:nth-child` selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug (see [#11632](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11632), [#11737](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11737)) in the Qt4 fork of WebKit (from 2010). It happens when `:nth-child()` or `:nth-of-type()` CSS3 selectors are used. The second time the selector is run, it returns a different result (most of the time `null`). The only known workaround is to use XPath expressions instead of CSS3 selectors. This bug is fixed in PhantomJS 2 as it uses a Qt5 fork of WebKit (version 538.1).

This is a minimal script to reproduce the issue on http://example.com (modified from [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11632#issuecomment-35297337)):

```
var casper = require('casper').create(),
    x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.start('http://example.com', function() {
    var selector = 'p:nth-child(3) > a',
        xpSelector = '//*[local-name()="p" and position()=3]/a';
    var first = this.exists(selector);
    var second = this.exists(selector);
    if(first !== second) {
        console.error('Expected First selector to equal the Second');
    } else {
        console.log('Passed');
    }
    first = this.exists(x(xpSelector));
    second = this.exists(x(xpSelector));
    if(first !== second) {
        console.error('Expected First selector to equal the Second');
    } else {
        console.log('Passed');
    }
}).run();
```

Output:

```
Expected First selector to equal the Second
Passed
```

Markup is:

```
<div>
    <h1>text</h1>
    <p>text</p>
    <p><a href="url">text</a></p>
</div>
```

The XPath expression looks a little awkward, because it directly reproduces the intended behavior of the CSS selector. Normally one would write `//p[2]/a`.

Comment: Glad I could help. If I had known that the `selector` in the question contained a `:nth-child`, this could've been solved much sooner.