# Count DOM elements with CasperJS' evaluate failed

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs

I've just got trouble with CasperJS.

I need to count table rows, since there are many tables that contain same information structure (lets say user table)
So I do some casperjs evaluate code like this

```
var table_rows1 = casper.evaluate(function(it){ return jQuery("#dResult > div:nth-child("+1+") > div > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child("+it+") > div:nth-child(1) > span > div").length; }, it);
```

It is iterator, it will increasing until reach the table element length.

So lets say we have 3 tables, so it will be 1,2,3
For it = 1, there are no problem occured, its print out the correct table[1] rows number.
But for next it, 2,3, it just print 1 for table rows number.
How it could be become so weird like this?

This is my CasperJS snippet:

```
function getNumber(it){
     window.__utils__.echo("it :"+it);
     var query = "#dResult > div:nth-child("+1+") > div > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child("+it+") > div:nth-child(1) > span > div";
     return jQuery(query).length;
}
var table_rows1 = casper.evaluate(getNumber, 1);
var table_rows2 = casper.evaluate(getNumber, 2);
var table_rows3 = casper.evaluate(getNumber, 3);

this.echo("table rows #1 :"+table_rows1);
this.echo("table rows #2 :"+table_rows2);
this.echo("table rows #3 :"+table_rows3);
```

And this is the html which I need to scrape...

This is for 1 table, there are many html tags like this

```
<div class="padd-b-rates">
        <div id="showRateWSMA0511000015CL096-CL124">
            <div class="bd-rate-in">
                <div class="rth1"><b>Room Category </b></div>
                <div class="rth2"><b>Breakfast</b></div>
                <div class="rth3"><b>Total Stay</b></div>
                <div class="rth4"><b>Room Status</b></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <span id="RateWSMA0511000015CL096-CL124">
    <div class="bd-rate-row">
        <div class="rtd1"><span class="rmname-rsht-rate">DELUXE (NRF)</span><i></i></div>
        <div class="rtd2"><span>Breakfast</span><i></i></div>
        <div class="rtd3"><span><a href="javascript:sHC.ShowPrice('WSMA0511000015','WSMA140400017', 'BB','CL096-CL124');">2,174,005.00 IDR</a></span><i></i></div>
        <div class="rtd4"><span class="btn-rsht-rate" onclick="sHC.jumpToPaxdetail(this);" hotelcode="WSMA0511000015" suppliercode="CL096-CL124" droomcatg="WSMA140400017-BB" roomstatus="Y" id="bookWSMA0511000015WSMA140400017-BB-CL096-CL124"><img border="0" src="/b2b/images/result-hotels/btnAV-v3.gif"></span></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bd-rate-row">
        <div class="rtd1"><span class="rmname-rsht-rate">EXECUTIVE (NRF)</span><i></i></div>
        <div class="rtd2"><span>Breakfast</span><i></i></div>
        <div class="rtd3"><span><a href="javascript:sHC.ShowPrice('WSMA0511000015','WSMA140400018', 'BB','CL096-CL124');">2,505,557.00 IDR</a></span><i></i></div>
        <div class="rtd4"><span class="btn-rsht-rate" onclick="sHC.jumpToPaxdetail(this);" hotelcode="WSMA0511000015" suppliercode="CL096-CL124" droomcatg="WSMA140400018-BB" roomstatus="Y" id="bookWSMA0511000015WSMA140400018-BB-CL096-CL124"><img border="0" src="/b2b/images/result-hotels/btnAV-v3.gif"></span></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bd-rate-row">
        <div class="rtd1"><span class="rmname-rsht-rate">DELUXE</span><i></i></div>
        <div class="rtd2"><span>Room Only</span><i></i></div>
        <div class="rtd3"><span><a href="javascript:sHC.ShowPrice('WSMA0511000015','WSMA05110034', 'RO','CL096-CL124');">2,743,860.00 IDR</a></span><i></i></div>
        <div class="rtd4"><span class="btn-rsht-rate" onclick="sHC.jumpToPaxdetail(this);" hotelcode="WSMA0511000015" suppliercode="CL096-CL124" droomcatg="WSMA05110034-RO" roomstatus="Y" id="bookWSMA0511000015WSMA05110034-RO-CL096-CL124"><img border="0" src="/b2b/images/result-hotels/btnAV-v3.gif"></span></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bd-rate-row">
        <div class="rtd1"><span class="rmname-rsht-rate">DELUXE</span><i></i></div>
        <div class="rtd2"><span>Breakfast</span><i></i></div>
        <div class="rtd3"><span><a href="javascript:sHC.ShowPrice('WSMA0511000015','WSMA05110034', 'BB','CL096-CL124');">2,847,470.00 IDR</a></span><i></i></div>
        <div class="rtd4"><span class="btn-rsht-rate" onclick="sHC.jumpToPaxdetail(this);" hotelcode="WSMA0511000015" suppliercode="CL096-CL124" droomcatg="WSMA05110034-BB" roomstatus="Y" id="bookWSMA0511000015WSMA05110034-BB-CL096-CL124"><img border="0" src="/b2b/images/result-hotels/btnAV-v3.gif"></span></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bd-rate-bottom">
            <div class="rsht-cxl" id="CancelPolicyWSMA0511000015CL096-CL124" onclick="sHC.rCancel('WSMA0511000015CL096-CL124','CL096-CL124');" title="Click for view cancellation policy">
                <textarea id="PolicyWSMA0511000015CL096-CL124" style="display:none"></textarea>
                Cancellation Policy         </div>
            <div class="rsht-promotion" id="FOCWSMA0511000015CL096-CL124" onmouseover="sHC.popupHotelFOC(this, 'WSMA0511000015CL096-CL124','CL096-CL124');" detail="" style="display:none;">(Special Promotion)</div>
            <div class="rsht-message" id="lyHotelMessageWSMA0511000015CL096-CL124"><blink><b><font color="red">Hotel Message</font> : </b></blink> <span id="HotelMessageWSMA0511000015CL096-CL124" style="word-wrap:break-word;">Complimentary WIFI internet access</span></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If there are another table structure like this, the evaluate function just return 1 or even 0...
so whats the problem about this case?

This is what I've got if I did my jQuery dom counting in inspect element chrome browser

```
jQuery("#dResult > div:nth-child("+1+") > div > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child("+1+") > div:nth-child(1) > span > div").length;
```

8

```
jQuery("#dResult > div:nth-child("+1+") > div > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child("+2+") > div:nth-child(1) > span > div").length;
```

15

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Please provide some markup and a bigger snippet of your code. It's probably related to scoping issues during iteration.

Comment: I'm already update my question...I'm also add the result if I do the jquery dom counting in google chrome inspect element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selectors look fine. There are multiple things that might have happened...

### Waiting

The site is not fully loaded (dynamic site/SPA) which means that you're trying to access those elements too early. You could for example wait for the first elements to appear and then access all of them:

```
casper.waitFor(function check(){
    return this.evaluate(getNumber, 1) > 0;
}, function then(){
    var table_rows1 = this.evaluate(getNumber, 1);
    var table_rows2 = this.evaluate(getNumber, 2);
    ...
});
```

### With XPath

PhantomJS has a bug with `:nth-child()` selectors which only appears for specific constellations. You can try to use XPath expressions for that.

```
function getNumber(it){
     var query = "//*[@id='dResult']/*["+1+"]/div/*[4]/*["+it+"]/*[1]/span/div";
     return __utils__.getElementsByXPath(query).length;
}
```

The reason I use `*[x]` instead of `div[x]` is because XPath takes the element name into account when querying according to a position, but CSS selectors do not.

### Different mobile page

Sometimes the server delivers a different page according to the user agent string or the viewport. PhantomJS has a default viewport size of 400x300. Maybe the page was dynamically changed by the page JavaScript.

- Check the screenshot (`casper.capture()`) whether the page looks the same way as in Chrome.
- Dump the page source with [`casper.debugHTML()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#debughtml) and compare it with the Chrome version.

### Generic problems

There may be other problems with the page. Look for errors with the various event handlers. Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)).

Comment: I'm already capture the page, and the image captured was in the same way with what displayed in my google chrome browser. But I will have to try your advice...will report to this immediately

Comment: Thats work, wow. Your xpath solution that match with my problem. So be it, the nth-child was the problem.
Btw, where I can read the casperjs nth-child bugs? What do you mean with "constellations"?
But thanks anyway...

Comment: I've written about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835506/waitforselector-passes-but-assertexists-fails-for-the-same-selector